# Creating a Transactional Email for a Contact Form

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

I want to create a transactional email to send to customers when they complete our contact form.

I have no issues with creating the content and copy for the email, but need guidance on a couple of points.

1. Is there way to personalise the email to each customer? I want the email to say Hello [Customer Name]. Is this possible?
2. Once the transactional email is created, how do I ensure it is send out when the contact form has been completed?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To create a new e-mail template, navigate to `System > Transactional Emails` in Magento's top Admin Panel menu and click the 'Add New Template' button.

In the top section select 'Contact Form' from the Template drop-down menu and click 'Load Template'. The default contact form e-mail template will be loaded in the Template section.

[image: Screenshot]

1. {{var data.name}} should give you the name
2. After saving the new transactional e-mail template, you still need to assign it to the store contact by navigating to `System > Configuration > Contacts`. Select your custom e-mail template in the Email Options section, click 'Save Config' and you should be all set.

[image]